# Error raising a complex number to a power

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

I am trying to do

> $(3+7i)^5$

which acording to WolframAlpha and Mathway should be:

> $23028−11228i$

Yet I instead get:
 $6123+14287i$

--

I'm getting that answer by doing:

> $3^5 (7i)^0 + 3^4 (7i)^1 + 3^3 (7i)^2 + 3^2 (7i)^3 + 3^1 (7i)^4 + 3^0 (7i)^5$

and then just combining the like terms. Could anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You missed all the $C^n_r$ terms.

Comment: I'm still learning this, can you link me to somewhere or let me know what that is? I'm kinda finding my way in the dark on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John pointed out in the comment, you have used
$$
(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n a^k b^{n-k},
$$
which is wrong. Instead, you should use
$$
(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^k b^{n-k}.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  An easier way to do this might be to first convert your number into polar form: $z = re^{i\theta}$.  Then $z^5 = re^{i5\theta}$.  From there, you can re-expand using Euler's formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can save time by doing it another way:

By Euler :$3+7i=e^{iarctan\frac 73}$,

which means $(3+7i)^5=e^{i5arctan\frac 73}$

Now use a calculator to evaluate $5arctan \frac 73$. If we know that $5arctan \frac 73=\phi$

Then by Euler's equation again: $(3+7i)^5=e^{i\phi}=cos\phi+isin\phi$ .
As to the reason why you didn't get it right:

$3^5 (7i)^0 + 3^4 (7i)^1 + 3^3 (7i)^2 + 3^2 (7i)^3 + 3^1 (7i)^4 + 3^0 (7i)^5$should actually be:

$3^5 (7i)^0 + 5*3^4 (7i)^1 + 10*3^3 (7i)^2 + 10*3^2 (7i)^3 + 5*3^1 (7i)^4 + 3^0 (7i)^5$.

To calculate the coefficients:
Suppose we want to expand $(a+b)^n$, then $(a+b)^n=\Sigma^n_{r=0} \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}a^rb^{n-r}$. Now you get it.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, but unfortunately I'm doing this for a very specific application and need it done in this way. I just need to learn what's missing from my above calculation. John said it's the Cnr terms, any idea where I can go from that?

Comment: you should notice that each term in the expansion should have a specific coefficient which is given by $\frac {m!}{n!(m-n)!}$.